# jQuery doesn't work on my server but does work in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery

This is starting to freak my out by now. What's happening here?

See no result on http://www.mauricekappelhof.nl/work/TemplateTest/Backend/menu.php?page=1
See working result on http://jsfiddle.net/x7bgF/

Oh, i want to replace spaces with an underscore. So if you type a space in the 'Titel' field, the 'link' field suppose to show the same, but then with an underscore.

It's about this piece of jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#title').keyup(function(e){
            var e = e || window.event;
            $('#link').val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '_'));
        });​
    });
```

Comment: How do you write script on server side?

Comment: Firebug gives a `SyntaxError: illegal character` on `menu.php?page=1 (line 50, col 5)`

Comment: it shows a `syntaxError: unexpected token ILLEGAL` on line 4 of this snippet.

Comment: Works fine on your server for me. (Latest version of Chrome)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have an illegal character

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#title').keyup(function(e){
        var e = e || window.event;
        $('#link').val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '_'));
    });? // <--  delete this and rewrite it
});
```

You can see it in notepad++

It's from copy and pasting from jsfiddle

Comment: Damn that's it, but so weird because i'm not seeing anything in Apple's TextEdit :?

Comment: @Maurice I've never used apple's textedit so I wouldn't know.  I think you can use notepad++ on OSX though if you use WINE to run it http://studiogreenleaf.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/notepad-on-mac-osx/

Answer (score 3):

I get:

> SyntaxError: illegal character
>
> });?
>
> menu.php?page=1 (line 50, col 5)

on my log (note that the ? isnt displayed on my firebug, seems there is a hidden character or something on your php file).

when you change encoding on the source code you will get:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#title').keyup(function(e){
        var e = e || window.event;
        $('#link').val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '_'));
    });â€‹
});
```

you may want to change your php file to UTF-8 if you are using that as encoding, firefox says you are using ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and I make a little change:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#title').keyup(function(e) {
        var e = e || window.event;
        $('#link').val($(this).val().replace("/\s/g", '_'));
    });
});
```